# Global Variable appending multiple copies of data while updating

Tags: java, android

I have created a class named "Global Services" which I use to save my data globally and access them in a different activity. But when I am calling the set() method, instead of overview the existing data instead it is appending that data. Below is my code.

I have even tried to remove the instance but still, it is appending the new data instead of overwriting.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GlobalServices {
    private static GlobalServices instance;
    String partner, leadsResponse;
    List<Leads> assignedList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Leads> unAssignedList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Inventory> listInventory = new ArrayList<>();

    private GlobalServices() {}

    public static GlobalServices getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new GlobalServices();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static void destory() {
        instance = null;
    }

    public String getPartner() {
        return partner;
    }

    public String getLeadsResponse() {
        return leadsResponse;
    }

    public List<Leads> getAssignedList() {
        return assignedList;
    }

    public List<Leads> getUnAssignedList() {
        return unAssignedList;
    }

    public List<Inventory> getListInventory() {
        return listInventory;
    }

    public void setPartner(String partner) {
        this.partner = partner;
    }

    public void setLeadsResponse(String leadsResponse) {
        this.leadsResponse = leadsResponse;
    }

    public void setAssignedList(List<Leads> assignedList) {
        this.assignedList = assignedList;
    }

    public void setUnAssignedList(List<Leads> unAssignedList) {
        this.unAssignedList = unAssignedList;
    }

    public void setListInventory(List<Inventory> listInventory) {
        this.listInventory = listInventory;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a code segment where these new lists are coming from. It seems that list objects your trying to set to global list must already have previous data as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're just assigning new references to your lists in `GlobalServices` but not creating new lists. This means as soon as you modify this reference from another place in your code, it will be reflected in the `GlobalServices` list as well. All you have to do is:

```
    public void setAssignedList(List<Leads> assignedList) {
        this.assignedList = new ArrayList<>(assignedList);
    }

    public void setUnAssignedList(List<Leads> unAssignedList) {
        this.unAssignedList = new ArrayList<>(unAssignedList);
    }

    public void setListInventory(List<Inventory> listInventory) {
        this.listInventory = new ArrayList<>(listInventory);
    }
```

This way a new copy will be created in memory for each list and the data will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I was wrong, but your code here is not a problem.
The problem might come from other part of your application.
The data you set might be the data that extend your current data.

Example you have

```
GlobalServices instance = GlobalServices.getInstance()
List<Inventory> listInventory1 = new ArrayList<>();
listInventory1.add(new Inventory());
instance.setListInventory(listInventory1); // now your inventory have one item

// In some where else in your project
List<Inventory> listInventory2 = instance.getListInventory(); // lisInventorys.size() equals 1
// Then you add more data to listInventory2 by mistake
listInventory2.add(new Inventory()); // listInventory2.size() equals 2
// Then you set back listInventory2 to your global service
instance.setListInventory(listInventory2); // now your inventory have two item
```

So, the data had been actually overwrite, it data just been extended by accident.